# SQL query select each type of form per employee

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm using MSSQL server 2008 and have two tables `forms` and `employees`.

`forms` contains all forms completed by employees, e.g.

```
[id][employeeId][formId]
```

There are only ever 6 types of forms each with their own id. How would I construct a query to list each employee with each type of form and whether they have been completed (exist in the `forms` table) e.g.

```
[employeeId][formType1][formType2][formType3]...
 1           1          null       1
 2           1          1          null
```

**EDIT:** My current query to list all the information that then needs to be 'filtered' down to the schema above:

```
SELECT  *
FROM forms as f
inner join employees as e on e.EmployeeID = f.EmployeeID
```

Comment: could you post the select you are using now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group by the employee ID and "count" the number of instances of each form type:

```
SELECT  employeeid,
    SUM(CASE WHEN f.ID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) formType1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN f.ID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) formType2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN f.ID = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) formType3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN f.ID = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) formType4,
    SUM(CASE WHEN f.ID = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) formType5,
    SUM(CASE WHEN f.ID = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) formType6
FROM forms as f
GROUP BY employeeid
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic +100 if I could

Comment: @Lee Lol'ed at you comment, D Stanley i suppose this is more efficent that my answer for the pure fact that you do all the operations over the same table instance ... Good to see new ways to so the same, Kudos!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could do the trick

```
SELECT emp.[employeeName], form1.formId as formType1, form2.formId as formType2, form3.formId as formType3, form4.formId as formType4, form5.formId as formType5, form6.formId as formType6 
FROM [database_name].dbo.[employees] as emp 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN [database_name].dbo.[form] as form1 ON (emp.[EmployeeID] = form1.[EmployeeID] AND form1.id='ID_FOR_THE_FORM1') 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN [database_name].dbo.[form] as form2 ON (emp.[EmployeeID] = form2.[EmployeeID] AND form2.id='ID_FOR_THE_FORM2') 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN [database_name].dbo.[form] as form3 ON (emp.[EmployeeID] = form3.[EmployeeID] AND form3.id='ID_FOR_THE_FORM3') 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN [database_name].dbo.[form] as form4 ON (emp.[EmployeeID] = form4.[EmployeeID] AND form4.id='ID_FOR_THE_FORM4') 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN [database_name].dbo.[form] as form5 ON (emp.[EmployeeID] = form5.[EmployeeID] AND form5.id='ID_FOR_THE_FORM5') 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN [database_name].dbo.[form] as form6 ON (emp.[EmployeeID] = form6.[EmployeeID] AND form6.id='ID_FOR_THE_FORM6') ;
```

Not exactly what are you looking for you can evalute if NULL then the employee not answer that form everything else he answer it. I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to see those employees too who has not completed any form then you might try this:

```
Select FormName, EmpName, id
FROM 
    (SELECT formID ,FormName , empID, EmpName
            FROM FormTypes  
                CROSS JOIN Emp) x
        LEFT JOIN Forms f on (x.empid = f.employeename and  x.formID = f.formID)
```